# Some examples to demonstrate compact support

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am an electrical engineer trying to learn some real analysis from the internet. Please provide an instructive example of a function with compact support and another function without compact support. Please explain why each function does or doesn't have compact support.

Comment: Do you know what "compact" and "support" mean separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
1 + x & \text{if } -1 \le x \le 0\\
1 - x & \text{if } 0 \le x \le 1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, $f(x)$ is nonzero precisely when $x \in (-1,1)$. Hence the support of $f$ is the closure $[-1,1]$. This is a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore compact.

The gaussian function $g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
g(x) = e^{-x^2}
$$
is continuous (even smooth). We have $g(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ so the support of $g$ is the entire real line $\mathbb{R}$ which is not compact (it's not bounded).

In both of the examples the function values go to $0$ as $x \to \pm\infty$, but  the intution is that a compactly supported function actually hits $0$ after a "finite"
distance.

Comment: Also, there are smooth functions with compact support, such as $\exp(-1/(1-|x|^2))$ for $|x|<1$.

Comment: @mr_e_man corrected, thanks. For pedagogical reasons I thought I'd avoid bump functions since their smoothness is not entirely obvious, but it's good to note that they exist.